# Inputs javascript

Tags: html, php, javascript

Помогите вывести и кнопку с формой отправки массива (код нашел!)

```
<script language ="JavaScript">
var i;
function selChange(n) {
var str = "";
for(i = 1; i <=n; i++){
   str += "<span>Автор: </span> <input name=\"Name"+ i +"  type=\"text\" tabindex=\"1\" ><br>";

   }

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = str;
}

</script>
<div class="wrap">
    <h3>Авторы публикации</h3>
        <span>Количество авторов:</span>
        <input name="n" type="text" tabindex="18" onChange="selChange(this.value)"/>
        <button>Выбрать</button><br/>
    <span id="container"></span>

</div>
```

Например если я выбираю 2 инпута мне выводит два инпута и сразу кнопку для отправки формы, что нужно изменить в js коде?

Comment: >выбираю 2 инпута

А где вы выбираете сколько инпутов?

p.s.@amf1k, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

p.p.s.@amf1k Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: <input name="n" type="text" tabindex="18" onChange="selChange(this.value)"/>
        <button>Выбрать</button><br/>

Comment: Т.е. если в этот n забьют цифру 2 - должно появиться 2 инпута, если 3 - то 3 и т.д.?

Comment: да , все верно и должно появится кнопка с формою отправки!

Answer (score 2):

Надо просто в начало вашего str загнать <form>,  а в конец submit -ный инпут и </form>. //[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/6t3wu/)

Comment: Как сделать чтобы можно было вводить только цифры у поля инпут при выборе количества инпутов, и как ограничить ввод количества инпутов?

Comment: @amf1k <input type="number" max="5">

Comment: max="5" делает ограничение на количество вводимых символов в инпуте, а мне нужно ограничение на добавление инпутов, думаю это можно реализовать на JS!)

Comment: @amf1k количество символов ограничивает maxlength, а не max. Вы бы сначала попробовали, чем писать такую чушь

Comment: type='number' не то( можно это все реализовать на js!

Comment: А смысл???